# What is up with these pigs?

Tags: dont-starve

I do not understand the pig dynamics in Don't Starve. I haven't really been bothered by any pigs (unless I go and attack one). But then I encountered these crazy pigs (sorry for the bad shot...I couldn't get too close!):

[image]

But yet I can walk around this area all day and have no problem with pig attacks:

[image]

So what's the difference? Why are the pigs in the first picture crazy and attack me on sight and the ones in the bottom picture are cool and let me wander around their area without a problem?

Comment: Feed meat to the normal ones - they follow you then and attack your enemies. Not sure about the others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the bushes in the first picture? Those pigs are not crazy, they're defending their harvest. By getting close to the berries you become a threat, so they attack you. So, if you want to befriend a pig, you better choose another one, and if you need berries get a free bush somewhere else or be prepared to fight. Otherwise, just walk around and they'll mind their own business.

Comment: The warrior pigs by the torches are great for helping out with hounds, though.  Just lead the hounds near them and let the pigs do the rest.  The nice thing is that the torches are such a good light source, it works at any time of day.

Comment: The same "torches" pigs can be found around other things than bushes: torches, grass, ...

Comment: They keep saying something about defending a King, too. Is there one?

Comment: @DavidM if there's one he's pretty visible, you cannot miss him. He's bigger than the other Pigmen and just stays there doing nothing the whole day. He's useful to get a lot of gold though.