# How do I befriend aggressive, overprotective pigs?

Tags: dont-starve

I'm in adventure mode, and this particular world does not have food – but it does have frog rain. Lots of frog rain.

That means tasty frog legs are basically my only food source, but I am simply not equipped to protect myself against these viscious beasts. I set out a lot of traps to catch them, but I can hardly do anything else, because I am constantly attacked by frogs. Not chop wood or set up camp or anything.

However, his Majesty the Pig King is nearby, and he has lots of minion pigs. They are, however, aggressive to me. I have tried walking in unarmed, and offering them (uncooked) frog legs, but that didn't work.

Is there any way I can befriend the pigs, and make them protect me against these beasts? Or at the very least, tolerate me in their presence, so I can use their base as a sanctuary?

I have read [this similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148616/what-is-up-with-these-pigs), but I am not sure the situation is the same, or if the pig behaviour have changed since. In fact, in my game (but in sandbox world) I could freely harvest berry farms near pig houses without intrusion. Those pigs loved me. Not like these other jerks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Guardian pigs- the ones with warpaint can be fed but cannot be bribed with food or controlled by the one-man band. They are too loyal to His Plumpness the Pig King.

Comment: I seem to remember bribing one of his pigs in a much earlier version of the game. Also, I am certain that it should be possible to interact with Jabba the Hog himself – has this feature been removed, or will the pigs only sometimes tolerate the player?

Comment: @Nix They'll tolerate a player if they are guarding His Imperial Fatass but they still can't be befriended. You can also find regular pigs nearby- you must have befriended one of them instead.

Comment: In this particular instance, they are attacking me on sight, even if I am not within their walls – I have not done anything to provoke this behaviour, I am a total bro. Oh well, I guess I will just need to get a bigger stick.

Comment: @Nix If it's a fort, it's an adventure mode thing. They're attacking because adventure mode hates you and wants you to die horribly.

Answer (score 0):

No. However, you can try running into the pig village whenever you are accosted by frogs. This should make the pigs and the frogs attack each other, and you can slip away. (Then come back to harvest the meat later.)